# Express roots of power serie as a power serie

Tags: calculus

Suppose that i have the following power serie :

$$A(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{i} x^{i} \text{ such that } \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\alpha_i = 1 \text{ and } \forall i,\;\alpha_i \ge0 $$

**Q:** For a given $a \in ]0,1[$, **is it possilble to found** some $(\beta_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that :

$$A(x)^a = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \beta_{j} x^{j} $$

If necessary, you can suppose furthermore that :

- the serie is *not* infinite in the sense that $\exists n, \forall i > n, \alpha_i = 0$
- $a = \frac{1}{m}$ for a given $m \in \mathbb{N}$

If it is possile, can we give some kind of close-form expression to the $\beta_i$ or found an algorythme to express them ?

If you have some references that might be related, it could help me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

$A(x)^{\alpha}$ is a multi-valued function. There is no neighborhood of $0$ in which there is an analytic branch, so the answer is NO, you don't have  such a series expansion.

Comment: I did not get anything you said, i'm sorry. Why would $A(x)^a$ be multi-valued ? A is a function from R to R and the function that sets x to the power $a$ si also a function from R to R. Both of them assign only one output to an input

Comment: When  $x<0$ we may have $A(x) <0$. So $A(x)^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha \log(A(x))}$ is undefined. You have to have some knowledge of Complex Analysis to assign some value to this expression.  In my answer I assumed that you were familiar with basic Complex Analysis.

Comment: You are right, in my problem $x$ is a complex and so might be $A(x)$. I do have some knownledge about complex analysis, but maybe not as much as you expected.